# How to load Yii modules component?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, yii-modules

When I did the steps like described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/27/how-to-access-a-component-of-a-module-from-within-the-module-itself/) I just get with config in config/main.php:

```
<?php
return array(
  'modules' => array(
    'tracking' => array(
      'components' => array(
        'tracking' => array(
          'foo' => 'bar'
)))));
```

this result, when I var_dump `Yii::app()->getModule('tracking')`:

```
object(TrackingModule)#148 (20) {
  ["defaultController"]=>  string(7) "default"
  ["layout"]=>  NULL
  ["controllerNamespace"]=>  NULL
  ["controllerMap"]=>  array(0) {}
  ["_controllerPath":"CWebModule":private]=>  NULL
  ["_viewPath":"CWebModule":private]=>  NULL
  ["_layoutPath":"CWebModule":private]=>  NULL
  ["preload"]=>  array(0) {}
  ["behaviors"]=>  array(0) {}
  ["_id":"CModule":private]=>  string(8) "tracking"
  ["_parentModule":"CModule":private]=>  NULL
  ["_basePath":"CModule":private]=>  string(79) "..."
  ["_modulePath":"CModule":private]=>  NULL
  ["_params":"CModule":private]=>  NULL
  ["_modules":"CModule":private]=>  array(0) {}
  ["_moduleConfig":"CModule":private]=>  array(0) {}
  ["_components":"CModule":private]=>  array(0) {}
  ["_componentConfig":"CModule":private]=>  array(1) {
    ["tracking"]=> array(1) {
      ["foo"]=> string(4) "bar"
    }
  }
  ["_e":"CComponent":private]=>  NULL
  ["_m":"CComponent":private]=>  NULL
}
```

I expect that I can access modules component via `Yii::app()->getModule('tracking')->tracking`. But as you see `Yii::app()->getModule('tracking')` has no component, just its config.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify class for component, for example in config (TrackingClassName):

```
'modules' => array(
    'tracking' => array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'components' => array(
            'tracking'  => array(
               'class' => 'TrackingClassName', 
            ),...
```

Comment: That worked for me. But why do I've to declare the components class name? Because when I generated the module via GII there's a line in module's init function: `$this->setImport(array(
   'tracking.models.*',
   'tracking.components.*',
  ));`.

Comment: setImport is like PHP include_once but all files eg. in tracking/components/*.php. Setting class name in config means 'new Class' when you first use it. You have to do both. Its logical because how Yii could know which class from components? Class name can be set inside module however IMO its better only when class name is dynamically changing.

Answer (score 0):

You can still access it via `Yii::app()->getModule('tracking')->tracking`. Component will be created before the first use.

Comment: When I do this (`Yii::app()->getModule('tracking')->tracking`) call I get just the php `call on a non-object` error.

Answer (score 0):

[See here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/27/how-to-access-a-component-of-a-module-from-within-the-module-itself/)

[Another Yii forum Post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/19394-module-and-loading-module-extensions/)